# iOS app icon localized

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect

I know there are a lot of subjects about this question but there is no recent and no up to date answers.
Can we localized an app icon both on XCode and iTunes Connect ? And if yes, how ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: He is just asking for an update on the matter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That it's not currently supported, check this link:

https://devforums.apple.com/message/330960

There are no updates since that, so it's still not possible, sorry.

Comment: So I have to create 2 apps if I want an english and a french icon app ?

Comment: That what it seems, sorry

Comment: Damn, not a good point for Apple. But a good one for you, thanks.